# OData WCF Service Self Updating DataModel

Tags: c#, wcf, devexpress, odata

I am having difficulty understanding how the DataModels.edmx (Entity Framework model) works in a OData (Open Data Protocol) WCF Services. If I am using an existing database on Microsoft SQL Server Management (MSSM) do the DataModels.edmx properties and stored procedures update themselves when there is a change to the database and stored procedures in MSSM? If not, is it possible to make them update on their own?

I am using the DevExpress DXTREME version of WCF OData if that matters, but I think this question is more about how WCF Services work fundamentally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edmx models will not automatically update themselves to reflect DB changes.

You'll need to open your edmx file in the designer, right click on the design surface and select "Update Model From database..."

Once you have updated the model you'll need to build that project. This builds your server side library of classes.

Once built, you need to right click on the service reference (in the project which references the OData service) and select "Update Service Reference". This updates your client side library of classes.

I've made a few assumptions about how your solution is structured and haven't used DXTEREME, so please let me know if there are complications.